# When defining a function that will operate on memory, is it more correct to pass addresses as void* or uint8*?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, types, casting

Most of the existing run-time memory functions accept or return void*, which enables passing of arguments without explicitly casting the pointer types. Should this pattern be replicated when creating custom memory functions?

In other words, which of the following is more correct, and why:

```
int read_bytes( void * dest, size_t count );
```

or

```
int read_bytes( uint8_t * dest, size_t count );
```

?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `void*`. Otherwise, every call to the function will look like:

```
int n = read_bytes((uint8_t*)&myVar, sizeof(myVar));
```

instead of just

```
int n = read_bytes(&myVar, sizeof(myVar));
```

Answer (score 2):

void* is a general purpose pointer in C/C++. It is used in cases where you don't want a specific type specified with the data and avoids the need to cast the pointer. It is also the pointer that you want to use with raw addresses.

You would use uint_t where you want to specify that you are really dealing with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1):

If you treat memory only as raw, opaque memory, and not as a sequence of bytes, then `void *` is an appropriate type. This may be idiomatic, for example, when using placement-new to create object in memory. There are also some traditional C APIs that use void pointers for memory references, like `memcpy` or `memchr`, so occasionally it can be convenient to use the same type.

On the other hand, if you're thinking of memory as an array of bytes, and especially if you want to access random bytes in memory (i.e. perform pointer or iterator arithmetic), you should absolutely use a char pointer type. There's a certain debate about which one is best; typically, for I/O you want plain `char` as the "system's I/O data type" (e.g. reading/writing I/O). On the other hand, if you want to operate on arithmetic byte values, `unsigned char` is more appropriate. The two types are layout-compatible, though, so feel free to treat one as the other if that's necessary.